# How to bind an array to select by Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to bind an object array to a select drop down, but I cannot figure out how to make this work, can someone suggest how to make this work?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="DisplayCtrl">
<select ng-model="eventName" ng-options="name.event for name in eventNames">
    <option value="">Select Event</option>
</select>
<p>Currently selected: {{eventName.description}} </p></div>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
function DisplayCtrl($scope) {
$scope.eventNames = [{
    event: "Function A",
    description: "Gaming"
}, {
    event: "Function B",
    description: "Basketball"
}, {
    event: "Function C",
    description: "Football"
}, {
    event: "Function D",
    description: "Dancing"
}];
$scope.eventName = $scope.eventNames[1].event;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ztABS/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With object-arrays, angular will store the *real* object in the model variable. So your preselection should do the same, thus:

```
$scope.eventName = $scope.eventNames[1].event;
```

should be:

```
$scope.eventName = $scope.eventNames[1];
```

see:

http://jsbin.com/uyuJuDO/1/